# Modal window not being opened: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '<property>' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, bootstrap-modal

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that is using bootstrap 3.4.1 and jQuery 2.2.4 and Kendo UI v2015.2.624.

**MY SCENARIO**:
In one of my views I have declared a modal window as below:

```
    <script src="~/Areas/Financial/Scripts/Operations.js"></script>     
    <!--Modal window-->
    <div style="background-color:yellow; display:none" class="well">
        <h2 style="color:black;">MODAL CONTAINER</h2>
        <div id="datos_fac_modal">
            <div id="datos_fac_modal_control"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Operations.js**:

```
function openModalWindow() {
    
var formId = $("form").attr("id");

var df = new IniClienteDatosFacturacion({
    data: { clienteId: $("#clienteId").valor() },
    callbacks: {
        confirm: function (e) {
            gestionarHiddens(formId);

            var acctNbr = $("#datos_fac_modal_control_numerocuentabancaria").val();

            var hdnCtaBanc = $('input[type=hidden][name=currentNumeroCuentaBancaria]');
            if (hdnCtaBanc.length == 0)
                $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="currentNumeroCuentaBancaria" value="' + acctNbr + '" />');
            else
                hdnCtaBanc.val(acctNbr);

            showLoading();  // show spinner

            $("#wfSubmit_5").click();
            $("#datos_fac_modal").getKendoWindow().close(); //  close modal window
            
        },
    }
});

$("#datos_fac_modal_control").ClienteDatosFacturacion(df); // See later in the post the function, it is within ControlClienteDatosFacturacion.js

var kWindow = $("#datos_fac_modal").getKendoWindow();
if ( kWindow == null)
{
    kWindow = $("#datos_fac_modal").kendoWindow({
        width: 1000,
        modal: true,
        close: function () { $("#datos_fac_modal_control").html(null); }
    }).getKendoWindow();
}

kWindow.center().open();        
return false;
}
```

**ControlClienteDatosFacturacion.js** :

```
$.fn.ClienteDatosFacturacion = function (params) {
var parentContainer = this;
var parentContainerSelector = this.selector;
var nombreControl = "ControlDatosFacturacion";

var Control = {        
    options: params,
    _data: null,
    _private: {
        dataToHTML: function (objDatos, container, soloDatosFac) {
            if (objDatos == null)
                return;

            var containerId = container.attr('id');
            var containerSelector = '#' + containerId;

            if (soloDatosFac == null || soloDatosFac == false) {
                $(containerSelector + '_clienteid').val(objDatos.datosCliente.clienteId);
                $(containerSelector + '_nombre').val(objDatos.datosCliente.nombre);
                $(containerSelector + '_nif').val(objDatos.datosCliente.cif);
                fillDropDown($(containerSelector + '_nacionalidad'), objDatos.Countries, objDatos.datosCliente.paisId);
                fillDropDown($(containerSelector + '_grupoclientes'), objDatos.GrupoClientes, objDatos.currentClientGroup);
                $(containerSelector + '_telefono').val(objDatos.datosCliente.telefono);
                $(containerSelector + '_sociedad').val(objDatos.datosCliente.sociedadId);
            }

            var ConstCustomerTypes = JsConstants().JsCustomer.CustomerTypes;

            var grupoclientes = null;
            var condicionesdepago = null;
            var diadepago = null;
            var formapago = null;
            var grupoimpuestos = null;
            var grupotesoreria = null;
            var tipoCliente = null;

            grupoclientes = objDatos.currentClientGroup;
            condicionesdepago = objDatos.currentCondicionPago;
            diadepago = objDatos.currentPayDay;
            formapago = objDatos.currentFormaPago;
            grupoimpuestos = objDatos.currentGrupoImpuestos;
            grupotesoreria = objDatos.currentTreasuryGroup;
            tipoCliente = objDatos.esClienteDefinitivo ? ConstCustomerTypes.Customer : ConstCustomerTypes.BusinessRelationship;
            $(containerSelector + '_tipocliente').val(tipoCliente);
            $(containerSelector + '_multivencimientos').val(objDatos.multivencimientos);
            fillDropDown($(containerSelector + '_condicionesdepago'), objDatos.CondicionesPago, condicionesdepago);
            $(containerSelector + '_diadepago').getKendoNumericTextBox().value(diadepago);
            fillDropDown($(containerSelector + '_formapago'), objDatos.FormaPago, formapago);
            fillDropDown($(containerSelector + '_grupoimpuestos'), objDatos.GrupoImpuestos, grupoimpuestos);
            fillDropDown($(containerSelector + '_grupotesoreria'), objDatos.GruposTresoreria, objDatos.currentTreasuryGroup);

            if (objDatos.isFormaPagoCuentaBancoEmpresa)
                fillDropDown($(containerSelector + '_cuentabancaria'), objDatos.CuentasBancoEmpresa, objDatos.currentCuentaBancaria);
            else {
                fillDropDown($(containerSelector + '_cuentabancaria'), objDatos.CuentasBancoCliente, objDatos.currentCuentaBancaria);
                $(containerSelector + '_numerocuentabancaria').val()
            }

            $(containerSelector + '_formapago').data("formasPagoBancoCliente", objDatos.FormasPagoBancoCliente);
            $(containerSelector + '_formapago').data("formasPagoBancoEmpresa", objDatos.FormasPagoBancoEmpresa);

            Control._private.updateCuentaBancariaInfo(containerSelector, objDatos.FormasPagoBancoCliente, objDatos.FormasPagoBancoEmpresa, objDatos.currentFormaPago);

            return;
        },
        htmlToData: function () {
            if (_data == null) {
                _data = new ClienteDatosFacturacion();
            }

            _data.clienteId = $(parentContainerSelector + '_clienteid').val();
            _data.datosCliente.clienteId = _data.clienteId;
            _data.datosCliente.nombre = $(parentContainerSelector + '_nombre').val();
            _data.clienteDto.cif = $(parentContainerSelector + '_nif').val();
            _data.datosCliente.paisId = $(parentContainerSelector + '_nacionalidad').getKendoDropDownList().dataItem();
            _data.currentClientGroup = $(parentContainerSelector + '_grupoclientes').getKendoDropDownList().dataItem();
            _data.datosCliente.telefono = $(parentContainerSelector + '_telefono').val();
            _data.datosCliente.sociedadId = $(parentContainerSelector + '_sociedad').val();

            _data.tipoCliente = $(parentContainerSelector + '_tipocliente').val();
            _data.multivencimientos = $(parentContainerSelector + '_multivencimientos').val();
            _data.diadepago = $(parentContainerSelector + '_diadepago').getKendoNumericTextBox().value();
            _data.formapago = $(parentContainerSelector + '_formapago').getKendoDropDownList().dataItem();
            _data.grupoimpuestos = $(parentContainerSelector + '_grupoimpuestos').getKendoDropDownList().dataItem();
            _data.currentTreasuryGroup = $(parentContainerSelector + '_grupotesoreria').getKendoDropDownList().dataItem();
            _data.currentCuentaBancaria = $(parentContainerSelector + '_cuentabancaria').getKendoDropDownList().dataItem();//
            _data.currentCondicionPago = $(parentContainerSelector + '_condicionesdepago').getKendoDropDownList().dataItem();
            _data.currentNumeroCuentaBancaria = $(parentContainerSelector + '_numerocuentabancaria').val();
            _data.currentInvoiceAccount = $(parentContainerSelector + '_cuentafacturacion').valor();
        },
        renderInnerContainers: function (container, params) {
            var containerId = container.attr('id');
            var containerSelector = container.selector;

            container.append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h3>' + params.ui.titleConfirmacionDatosCliente + '</h3></div></div>');

            var row1Html = '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-8 disabled style="background-color: lightgrey;">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.nombre, container) + '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-4 disabled style="background-color: lightgrey;">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.clienteId, container) + '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            container.append(row1Html);

            var row2Html = '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-4 required" >' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.nacionalidad, container) + '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-4 required">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.nif, container) + '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-4 disabled style="background-color: lightgrey;">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.telefono, container) + '</div>' +
            '</div>';
            container.append(row2Html);

            container.append('<div class="row"><div class="col-md-12"><h3>' + params.ui.titleDatosFacturacion + '</h3></div></div>');

            var row3Html = '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-4">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.cuentafacturacion, container) + '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-4 required">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.diadepago, container) + '</div>' +
                '<div class="col-md-4 required">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.condicionesdepago, container) + '</div>' +
            '</div>';
            container.append(row3Html);

            var row4Html = '<div class="row">' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4 required">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.grupoclientes, container) + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4 required">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.grupoimpuestos, container) + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4 required">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.grupotesoreria, container) + '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            container.append(row4Html);

            var row5Html = '<div class="row">' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4 required">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.formapago, container) + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.cuentabancaria, container) + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="col-md-4">' + getContainerHtmlFromField(params.fields.numerocuentabancaria, container) + '</div>' + //agregar placeholder al input por parámetro
                '</div>';
            container.append(row5Html);

            var rowBotoneraHtml = '<div class="row botonera-wf">' +
                    '<div id="' + containerId + '_botonera" name="' + containerId + '_botonera" class="col-md-12">' +
                        '<input type="button" id="' + containerId + '_btnConfirm" value="Confirmar datos" class="btn btn-success k-button" />' +
                        '<input type="button" id="' + containerId + '_btnCancel" value="Cancelar" class="btn btn-default k-button" />' +
                    '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            container.append(rowBotoneraHtml);
            $(containerSelector + "_btnConfirm").on("click", function (e) { Control.onConfirmClick(e); });
            $(containerSelector + "_btnCancel").on("click", function (e) { Control.onCancelClick(e); });
            //Hiddens
            var hiddens = ' <input type="hidden" id="' + containerId + '_sociedad" name="' + containerId + '_sociedad" />' +
                '<input type="hidden" id="' + containerId + '_tipocliente" name="' + containerId + '_tipocliente" />' +
                '<input type="hidden" id="' + containerId + '_multivencimientos" name="' + containerId + '_multivencimientos" />';
            container.append(hiddens);

            return;
        },
        fillInnerContainers: function (container, params) {
            var containerId = container.attr('id');
            var containerSelector = container.selector;

            var p1 = { clienteId: "" };
            $(containerSelector + '_cuentafacturacion').ControlBusquedaCliente(p1);
            $(document).on(containerId + '_cuentafacturacion_recordSelected', function (e, selectedValue) {
                var gd = $('#' + e.target.id + '_gridMatches').getKendoGrid();
                var cteId = $(container.selector + '_clienteid').val();
                var selectedCuentaFac = selectedValue.clienteId;

                var cuentaFacRequest = $.ajax({
                    url: Control.options.data.urlDatosFacturacion,
                    method: "GET",
                    data: { clienteId: selectedCuentaFac }
                }).done(function (ctaFacResponse) {
                    if (ctaFacResponse != null)
                        Control._private.cambiarDatosFacturacion(ctaFacResponse, container);
                }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    if (typeof errorCallback === "function")
                        request.fail(errorCallback);
                });
            });

            var containerNac = $(containerSelector + '_' + params.fields.nacionalidad.fieldName);
            var controlNacionalidad = containerNac.kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: { data: null },
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                optionLabel: params.fields.nacionalidad.placeholder,
                change: Control._private.htmlToData
            });

            $("#" + containerId + "_nif").change(function () { Control._private.htmlToData() })
            $(containerSelector + "_diadepago").kendoNumericTextBox({
                min: 0,
                decimals: 0,
                format: '0.',
                change: Control._private.htmlToData
            });
            var containerCP = $(containerSelector + '_condicionesdepago');
            var controlCondicionesDePago = containerCP.kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: { data: null },
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                optionLabel: params.fields.condicionesdepago.placeholder,
                change: Control._private.htmlToData
            });
            var containerGC = $(containerSelector + '_grupoclientes');
            var controlGrupoClientes = containerGC.kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: { data: null },
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                optionLabel: params.fields.grupoclientes.placeholder,
                change: Control._private.htmlToData
            });
            var containerIMP = $(containerSelector + '_grupoimpuestos');
            var controlGrupoImpuestos = containerIMP.kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: { data: null },
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                optionLabel: params.fields.grupoimpuestos.placeholder,
                change: Control._private.htmlToData
            });
            var containerGT = $(containerSelector + '_grupotesoreria');
            var controlGrupoTesoreria = containerGT.kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: { data: null },
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                optionLabel: params.fields.grupotesoreria.placeholder,
                change: Control._private.htmlToData
            });
            var containerFP = $(containerSelector + '_formapago');
            var controlFormaPago = containerFP.kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: { data: null },
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                optionLabel: params.fields.formapago.placeholder,
                change: function (e) {
                    var containerCB = $(containerSelector + '_cuentabancaria');
                    var controlCuentaBancaria = containerCB.getKendoDropDownList();
                    controlCuentaBancaria.select(0);
                    $(containerSelector + '_numerocuentabancaria').val(null);
                    $(containerSelector + '_numerocuentabancaria').prop("readonly", "readonly");

                    Control._private.updateCuentaBancariaInfo(containerFP.selector, containerFP.data("formasPagoBancoCliente"), containerFP.data("formasPagoBancoEmpresa"), e.sender.value());
                    Control._private.htmlToData();
                }
            });
            var containerCB = $(containerSelector + '_cuentabancaria');
            var controlCuentaBancaria = containerCB.kendoDropDownList({
                dataSource: { data: null },
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                optionLabel: params.fields.cuentabancaria.placeholder,
                dataBound: function (e) {
                    var senderDataItem = e.sender.dataItem();
                    Control._private.updateNumeroCuenta(senderDataItem, containerSelector);
                },
                change: function (e) {
                    var senderDataItem = e.sender.dataItem();
                    Control._private.updateNumeroCuenta(senderDataItem, containerSelector);
                    Control._private.htmlToData();
                }
            });

            return;
        },
    data: function (newValue) {
        if (newValue == null)
            return _data;
        else {
            _data = newValue;
            this._private.dataToHTML(newValue, parentContainer, false);

        }
    },
    appendDataToForm: function (formId) {
        var form = formId == null ? $("form") : $("#" + formId);

        var sampleData = new ClienteDatosFacturacion();

        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.currentClientGroup == null ? null : _data.currentClientGroup.value, name: 'datos.currentClientGroup', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.currentCondicionPago == null ? null : _data.currentCondicionPago.value, name: 'datos.currentCondicionPago', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form); 
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.datosCliente.paisId == null ? null : _data.datosCliente.paisId.value, name: 'datos.currentCountry', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.clienteDto.cif == null ? null : _data.clienteDto.cif, name: 'datos.clienteDto.cif', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.currentCuentaBancaria == null ? null : _data.currentCuentaBancaria.value, name: 'datos.currentCuentaBancaria', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.formapago == null ? null : _data.formapago.value, name: 'datos.currentFormaPago', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.grupoimpuestos == null ? null : _data.grupoimpuestos.value, name: 'datos.currentGrupoImpuestos', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.currentInvoiceAccount, name: 'datos.currentInvoiceAccount', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.currentMultivencimiento, name: 'datos.currentMultivencimiento', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.currentCuentaBancaria == null ? null : _data.currentCuentaBancaria.value, name: 'datos.currentNombreCuentaBancaria', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.currentNumeroCuentaBancaria == null ? null : _data.currentNumeroCuentaBancaria, name: 'datos.currentNumeroCuentaBancaria', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.diadepago, name: 'datos.currentPayDay', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.currentTreasuryGroup == null ? null : _data.currentTreasuryGroup.value, name: 'datos.currentTreasuryGroup', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.currentUserSociedadId, name: 'datos.currentUserSociedadId', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);

        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.esClienteDefinitivo, name: 'datos.esClienteDefinitivo', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.isFormaPagoCuentaBancoCliente, name: 'datos.isFormaPagoCuentaBancoCliente', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
        $('<input>').attr({ value: _data.isFormaPagoCuentaBancoEmpresa, name: 'datos.isFormaPagoCuentaBancoEmpresa', type: 'hidden' }).appendTo(form);
    },
    validateFormData: function () {
        var error = "";

        if (_data.esClienteDefinitivo == false && (_data.datosCliente.paisId.value == null || _data.datosCliente.paisId.value == undefined || _data.datosCliente.paisId.value === "")) {
            error = "El campo nacionalidad debe estar informado";
            return error;
        }

        if (_data.esClienteDefinitivo == false && (_data.clienteDto.cif == null || _data.clienteDto.cif == undefined || _data.clienteDto.cif === "")) {
            error = "El campo NIF debe estar informado";
            return error;
        }

        if (_data.esClienteDefinitivo == true && (_data.currentInvoiceAccount == null || _data.currentInvoiceAccount == undefined || _data.currentInvoiceAccount === "")) {
            error = "La cuenta de facturación debe estar informada";
            return error;
        }

        if (_data.currentCondicionPago == null || _data.currentCondicionPago == undefined || _data.currentCondicionPago === "") {
            error = "El campo nacionalidad debe estar informado";
            return error;
        }

        if (_data.currentClientGroup.value == null || _data.currentClientGroup.value == undefined || _data.currentClientGroup.value === "") {
            error = "El campo grupo de clientes debe estar informado";
            return error;
        }

        if (_data.currentGrupoImpuestos == null || _data.currentGrupoImpuestos == undefined || _data.currentGrupoImpuestos === "") {
            error = "El campo grupo de impuestos debe estar informado";
            return error;
        }

        if (_data.currentTreasuryGroup.value == null || _data.currentTreasuryGroup.value == undefined || _data.currentTreasuryGroup.value === "") {
            error = "El campo grupo de tesorería debe estar informado";
            return error;
        }

        if (_data.formapago.value == "A" || _data.formapago.value == "S" || _data.formapago.value == "G") {
            if (_data.currentCuentaBancaria == "") {
                error = "Debe informarse un número de cuenta";
                return error;
            } 
        }
        return error;
    },
    render: function (container, params) {
        this._private.renderInnerContainers(container, params); //pinta los containers de los campos del control
        this._private.fillInnerContainers(container, params); //convierte los containers en controles (para los campos que usen controles)
        this.updateFromServer(params.data.urlDatosFacturacion, params.data.urlClientes, params.data.clienteId, container, null, null);
        return;
    },
    updateFromServer: function (urlGetDatosFacturacion, urlGetClientes, clienteId, container, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        var request = $.ajax(
            {
                url: urlGetDatosFacturacion,
                method: "GET",
                data: { clienteId: clienteId },
            }
        );

        request.done(function (response) {
            if (response != null) {
                container.getClienteDatosFacturacion().data(response);
                var clientePromise = $(container.selector + '_cuentafacturacion').fillControlClienteByClienteId(response.currentInvoiceAccount, response.datosCliente.sociedadId, urlGetClientes);

                if (clientePromise != null) {
                    clientePromise.done(function (clienteResponse) {
                        var clienteData = clienteResponse[0];
                        if (clienteData.clienteId != clienteId) //si clienteId no está en scope aquí, probar response.clienteId
                        {
                            logToConsole("Hacer otra llamada para actualizar los datos de facturación, porque la cuenta de facturación no es el mismo cliente al que se le hace la oferta.");
                            var cuentaFacRequest = $.ajax({
                                url: urlGetDatosFacturacion,
                                method: "GET",
                                data: { clienteId: clienteData.clienteId }
                            }).done(function (ctaFacResponse) {
                                container.getClienteDatosFacturacion().data(ctaFacResponse);
                            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                if (typeof errorCallback === "function")
                                    request.fail(errorCallback);
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            Control._private.htmlToData();
                            var senderDataItem = $(parentContainerSelector + "_cuentabancaria").getKendoDropDownList().dataItem();
                            Control._private.updateNumeroCuenta(senderDataItem, parentContainerSelector);
                        }
                    });
                }

                if (typeof successCallback === "function")
                    successCallback(response);
            }
        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            if (typeof errorCallback === "function")
                request.fail(errorCallback);
        });

        return;
    },

    //events
    onConfirmClick: function (e) {
         // here some stuff
    },
    onCancelClick: function (e) {
         // here some stuff
    },
};

this.data(nombreControl, Control);
Control.render(this, params);
return this.data(nombreControl);
};
```

Above ControlClienteDatosFacturacion.js is included in the master page ..\Views\Shared_Layout.cshtml using below line of code:

```
@{
    String pathJs = "http://mycontrols.companyname.com";
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="@pathJs/Scripts/myControls/ClienteDatosFacturacion/ControlClienteDatosFacturacion.js"></script>
```

**PROBLEM** :
When I click a button on the view it calls function openModalWindow (Within Operation.js file), but modal window does not show.

It fails executing ClienteDatosFacturacion function within ControlClienteDatosFacturacion.js, in this piece of code:

```
        fillInnerContainers: function (container, params) {
            var containerId = container.attr('id');
            var containerSelector = container.selector;

            var p1 = { clienteId: "" };
            $(containerSelector + '_cuentafacturacion').ControlBusquedaCliente(p1); // here it crashes
```

ControlBusquedaCliente is a function defined in another js and its content is as below.
It crashes when executing the line of code of the conditional, it says:

> here it crashes saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'toLowerCase' of undefined.

```
$.fn.ControlBusquedaCliente = function (params) {
    if ($(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'div') // here it crashes saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined.
    {
        // here some stuff
    }
    else
        logToConsole('Error: ControlBusquedaCliente sólo se puede instanciar sobre una div');
}
```

So any ideas how can I solve this?

Comment: Yes: make a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: add "debugger; " to the line above where you get the error. In your browser dev tools, inspect what this is, and what $(this) returns, and why there is no tagName property on it.